How to use condition and variable creating for Azure Pipeline correctly
I have azure-pipelines.yaml file into the project which looks like this:
# Using Piper general purpose pipeline for Azure with pipeline optimization

trigger:
  - main

resources:
  repositories:
    - some repositories

      

extends:
  template: sap-piper-pipeline.yml@piper-pipeline-azure
  parameters:
    acceptancePostSteps:
      - task: piper@1
        displayName: Prepare-Wiremock
        inputs:
          stepName: shellExecute
          flags: '--verbose true --sources ".pipeline/prepareWiremock.sh"'
          dockerImage: 'ppiper/cf-cli:latest'
      - task: piper@1
        displayName: Execute-Integration-Tests
        inputs:
          stepName: shellExecute
          flags: '--verbose true --sources .pipeline/executeIntegrationTests.sh'
          dockerImage: 'devxci/mbtci-java17-node18:latest'
      - task: piper@1
        displayName: Deploy to Dev
        inputs:
          stepName: cloudFoundryDeploy
          flags: "--apiEndpoint some endpoint"

In my case I have new maven-project called api-test-framework as a part of current with junit tests and I need to add executing of this tests to the current pipeline ONLY if some changes adopted in specific folder let's say with path: src/test/java/base/specificfolder
I have tried to do it in a such way (I just added it before Deploy to Dev task):
- task: PowerShell@2
        displayName: Check for changes
        inputs:
          targetType: 'inline'
          script: |
              $changes = git diff --name-only origin/main -- folder/where/I/need/to/check/changes
              if ($changes) {
                Write-Output "##vso[task.setvariable variable=isChangesDetected]true"
              }
              else {
                Write-Output "##vso[task.setvariable variable=isChangesDetected]false"
              }
      - task: piper@1
        displayName: Execute-Prompt-Tests
        inputs:
          stepName: shellExecute
          flags: '--verbose true --sources .pipeline/execute-api-tests.sh'
          dockerImage: 'devxci/mbtci-java17-node18:latest'
          condition: and(succeeded(), eq(variables['isChangesDetected'], 'true'))

I'm not a DevOps engineer and can't check it, but maybe somebody know the best way for my case.
Maybe it can be done more simpler, for example without first task and just with some variable which I can declare?

No other ways better than using the 'git diff' command to check whether there are changes made in the directory "src/test/java/base/specificfolder". Azure Pipelines also does not have predefined variables can be used to fetch the list of modified files.
So, I recommend you keep the 'git diff' command.
- task: PowerShell@2
  displayName: Check for changes
  env:
    SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN: $(System.AccessToken)
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: |
      Write-Host "Getting the count of commits associated with this build..."
      $prefix_url = "$(System.CollectionUri)"
      $project = "$(System.TeamProject)"
      $buildId = $(Build.BuildId)
      $url = "${prefix_url}${project}/_apis/build/builds/${buildId}/changes?includeSourceChange=true&api-version=7.0"
      $headers = @{Authorization = "Bearer $env:SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN"}
      $response=Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Headers $headers
      $changesCount = $response.count
      Write-Host "The count of commits is $changesCount."

      Write-Host "Detecting if the commits contain modified files under the specified folder (src/test/java/base/specificfolder)..."
      $changes = git diff HEAD HEAD~$changesCount --name-only -- src/test/java/base/specificfolder
      if ($changes.count -gt 0) {
        Write-Output "##vso[task.setvariable variable=isChangesDetected]true"
      }
      else {
        Write-Output "##vso[task.setvariable variable=isChangesDetected]false"
      }

- task: piper@1
  displayName: Execute-Prompt-Tests
  condition: and(succeeded(), eq(variables['isChangesDetected'], 'true'))
  inputs:
    stepName: shellExecute
    flags: '--verbose true --sources .pipeline/execute-api-tests.sh'
    dockerImage: 'devxci/mbtci-java17-node18:latest'


@ArtemiyStankevich, You're welcome. Have you tried the PowerShell script I shared, and is it helpful for you?
